# Validating mustache templates using schemata

Tags: validation, templates, mustache, lint

we're having multiple Moodle templates and which sometimes overwrite some mustache files of the plugins. The problem we're now facing is that when we change something in an underlying plugin, it sometimes break the templates.
So the question came up is, if it would be possible to validate a mustache template against another template - if it has the same structure. Another idea is, for JSON and XML there're specifications for Schemata (e.g. https://json-schema.org). For mustache we were unable to find something like this. Is there anything similar for mustache available? An idea we were thinking about writing a JSON schemata, convert the mustache file to a JSON object an validate it against the JSON schemata.

Anyone facing a similar issue or having an idea how it could work?

Comment: Are you *intentionally* changing plugin templates? Why? What do you mean by "same structure"? Are you primarily interested in validation in PHP or in JavaScript?